# Grafana configure Cognito Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito, grafana

I have on AWS two Grafana EC2 instances back an ALB.
Now I would configure access using AWS Cognito.

I'm trying to set **grafana.ini** as below:

```
[server]
protocol = http
#domain = grafana.mydomain.com
root_url = https://grafana.mydomain.com
serve_from_sub_path = true

[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
auto_login = false
client_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
client_secret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user_pool_id = eu-west-1_xxxxxxxxx
auth_url = https://myapp.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/auth2/authorize
token_url = https://myapp.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
region = eu-west-1
allow_sign_up = false
allowed_groups = "arn:aws:cognito:eu-west-1:000000000000:userpool/eu-west-1_xxxxxxxx:group/grafana-read", "arn:aws:cognito:eu-west-1:000000000000:userpool/eu-west-1_xxxxxxxx:group/grafana-admin"
role_attribute_path = contains(info.roles[*], 'grafana-admin') && 'Admin' || contains(info.roles[*], 'grafana-read') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'
```

When I try to connect to ALB by browser on:
`https://grafana.mydomain.com/generic_oauth/login` I receive the error:

```
https://myapp.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this callback url

```
https://grafana.mydomain.com/login/generic_oauth
```

Instead of:

```
https://grafana.mydomain.com/generic_oauth/login
```

Also add auth_uri parameter to grafana.ini:

```
 auth_url:https://{domain}.auth.${region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have Cognito `redirect_mismatch` error. That means you didn't configure Cognito client correctly. I bet problem is misconfigured `callback URLs`. You will see requested URI in the auth request to Cognito (there is redirect get parameter - it is generated by Grafana).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, do you have any example?

Comment: @MarcoFerrara No, I don't have. I recommended to check auth request and `requested_uri` parameter. I guess you will have there `https://grafana.mydomain.com/login/generic_oauth`. But your Grafana config is weird, e.g. `serve_from_sub_path=true, region = eu-west-1`, so it can be different.